# Images not being shown when using webpack and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, webpack

**My issue:** I want to have two images as background images. I included them in my project and I'm using file-loader to bundle them using webpack. And as long as I'm in development environment (so using webpack-dev-server) they appear in my app correctly. But when I deployed the app to Heroku, the background images are gone. My guess is that something is wrong with my node server since all is working fine with webpack-dev-server.

**My question:** what do I have to do to have images in both development and production environments? Change something in Node.js? Use another loader? Change how I import pictures?

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: ".",
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        inline: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        port: 8888
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                        plugins: ["transform-class-properties"]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {}
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /^.*\.(css|scss)$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader?importLoaders=1&modules&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
                    'postcss-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ],
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**webpack.prod.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    plugins: [
        new UglifyJSPlugin({
            sourceMap: true
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                        plugins: ["transform-class-properties"]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {}
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /^.*\.(css|scss)$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader?importLoaders=1&modules&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
                    'postcss-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ],
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8888;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'))
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('server started');
```

**example image usage, ShareABook.scss**

```
@import '../../theme/shareABook_theme.scss';
@import "../../theme/mixins.scss";

.shareABook_wrapper {

      @include centre-inside-div;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    .firstComponent {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      @include centre-inside-div;
      flex-direction: column;
      .background {
        background-image: url('../../media/images/book4.jpg');
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 1253px;
        width: 1880px;
        z-index: 1;
        display: block;
        filter: opacity(0.5);
      }
      .welcomeMessage {
        z-index: 9999;
        position: absolute;
        font-size: $font-size-typo-display-4;
        font-weight: $font-weight-bold;
        margin-top: -10rem;
        text-align: center;
        .mainMessage {
          font: $fancy-font;
        }
      }
    }
```

Below is my files structure. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide the full uncollapsed project structure. I cant tell where images stores or your scss files stores. But its enough.

For example, if your images all stores in "src/media/images".

Step 1:

```
app.use('/src/media/images/', express.static(__dirname, 'src', 'media', 'images'));
```

Add this to your server.js, which makes sure images can be accessed from node.js.

Step 2:

```
entry: {
    publicPath: '/src/media/images/',
}
```

Add this to your webpack.dev.js, which makes sure images can be accessed from webpack-dev-server.

Step 3:

```
.background {
    background-image: url('/src/media/images/***.jpg');
}
```

Change all your background image path in your scss files.

Then its done.All your images can be all accessed by both your node.js and webpack-dev-server.

Comment: No, they're not in src. I updated my question with full file structure.